# Fourier decomposition range in field quantization procedure

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, field-theory, mathematical-physics, fourier-transform

Consider the complex Klein-Gordon field (in finite volume $V$), which can be expanded in terms of plane waves as:
$$
\phi\left(\mathbf{x},t\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}\sum_{\mathbf{k}}\left(A_{\mathbf{k}}\left(t\right)e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}+B_{\mathbf{k}}^{\ast}\left(t\right)e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\right)
$$
where $A_{\mathbf{k}}\left(t\right)=A_{\mathbf{k}}e^{-i\omega_{k}t}$ and $B_{\mathbf{k}}^{\ast}\left(t\right)=B_{\mathbf{k}}^{\ast}e^{i\omega_{k}t}$ are the Fourier coefficients and $\omega_{k}^{2}=\mathbf{k}^{2}c^{2}+\frac{m^{2}c^{4}}{\hbar^{2}}$.

By promoting these coefficients to operators we obtain the quantized version:

$$
\hat{\phi}\left(\mathbf{x},t\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}\sum_{\mathbf{k}}\left(\hat{A}_{\mathbf{k}}\left(t\right)e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}+\hat{B}_{\mathbf{k}}^{\dagger}\left(t\right)e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\right)
$$

and the conjugate field:

$$\hat{\pi}\left(\mathbf{x},t\right)=\frac{i}{\sqrt{V}}\sum_{\mathbf{k}}\frac{\omega_{k}}{c^{2}}\left(\hat{A}_{\mathbf{k}}^{\dagger}\left(t\right)e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}-\hat{B}_{\mathbf{k}}\left(t\right)e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\right)$$

where $\left[\hat{A}_{\mathbf{k}},\hat{A}_{\mathbf{k}^{\prime}}^{\dagger}\right]=\left[\hat{B}_{\mathbf{k}},\hat{B}_{\mathbf{k}^{\prime}}^{\dagger}\right]=\frac{\hbar c^{2}}{2\omega_{k}}\delta_{\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k}^{\prime}}$.

Typically, we impose periodic boundary conditions such that

$$
\mathbf{k}=2\pi\left(\frac{n_{x}}{L_{x}},\frac{n_{y}}{L_{y}},\frac{n_{z}}{L_{z}}\right),\quad n_{x},n_{y},n_{z}\in\mathbb{Z}
$$

Exactly the same approach is used in the [quantization of the electromagnetic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_of_the_electromagnetic_field). There, the vector potential is expanded as:

$$
\displaystyle \mathbf {A} (\mathbf {r} ,t)=\sum _{\mathbf {k} }\sum _{\mu =\pm 1}\left(\mathbf {e} ^{(\mu )}(\mathbf {k} )a_{\mathbf {k} }^{(\mu )}(t)e^{i\mathbf {k} \cdot \mathbf {r} }+{\bar {\mathbf {e} }}^{(\mu )}(\mathbf {k} ){\bar {a}}_{\mathbf {k} }^{(\mu )}(t)e^{-i\mathbf {k} \cdot \mathbf {r} }\right)
$$

However, in that Wikipedia entry they write:

> "In this summation $\mathbf{k}$ runs over one side, positive or negative"

I was always under the impression that the summation $\sum_{\mathbf{k}}$ (and in the $V\to\infty$ case - integration) in field expansions is always performed over **all** possible $\mathbf{k}$ modes - both positive and negative (please correct me if I'm wrong). In other words $\sum_{\mathbf{k}}=\sum_{\mathbf{k}\in S}$ where $S$ is a "symmetric" set in the sense that for every $\mathbf{k} \in S$ we have $-\mathbf{k} \in S$. This, in particular, allows one to deduce things like

$$
\left[\hat{\pi}\left(\mathbf{x},t\right),\hat{\pi}^{\dagger}\left(\mathbf{x}^{\prime},t\right)\right]=\dots=\frac{\hbar}{2c^{2}V}\sum_{\mathbf{k}}\underbrace{\omega_{k}\left(-e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\left(\mathbf{x}^{\prime}-\mathbf{x}\right)}+e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\left(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}^{\prime}\right)}\right)}_{\text{antisymmetric in }\mathbf{k}}=0
$$

or

$$
\hat{\phi}\left(\mathbf{x},t\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}\sum_{\mathbf{k}}\left(\hat{A}_{\mathbf{k}}\left(t\right)+\hat{B}_{\mathbf{-k}}^{\dagger}\left(t\right)\right)e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}
$$

(since $\sum_{\mathbf{k}}=\sum_{-\mathbf{k}}$ due to the symmetric nature of the summation over $S$).

Assuming my understanding is correct, how can it be reconciled with the claim in the cited Wikipedia article? If my reasoning is incorrect, I'd like to known why.

---

**Edit** (in response to a comment): I don't see how the condition that the field must be real resolves the contradiction. In the case of the free scalar field the requirement $\phi=\phi^{\dagger}$ implies $\hat{A}_{\mathbf{k}}\left(t\right)=\hat{B}_{\mathbf{k}}\left(t\right)$ which means that

$$\hat{\phi}\left(\mathbf{x},t\right)=\sum_{\mathbf{k}}\left(\hat{A}_{\mathbf{k}}\left(t\right)e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}+\hat{A}_{\mathbf{k}}^{\dagger}\left(t\right)e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\right)=\sum_{\mathbf{k}}\left(\hat{A}_{\mathbf{k}}\left(t\right)+\hat{A}_{-\mathbf{k}}^{\dagger}\left(t\right)\right)e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}$$

However:

a) I don't see how this leads to $\hat{A}_{\mathbf{k}}^{\dagger}\left(t\right)=\hat{A}_{-\mathbf{k}}\left(t\right)$

b) Even if $\hat{A}_{\mathbf{k}}^{\dagger}\left(t\right)=\hat{A}_{-\mathbf{k}}\left(t\right)$ holds, I fail to see how it implies that

$$
\hat{\phi}\left(\mathbf{x},t\right)=\sum_{\text{all}\,\mathbf{k}}\left(\hat{A}_{\mathbf{k}}\left(t\right)+\hat{A}_{-\mathbf{k}}^{\dagger}\left(t\right)\right)e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}=\sum_{\mathbf{k}>0}\left(\hat{A}_{\mathbf{k}}\left(t\right)+\hat{A}_{-\mathbf{k}}^{\dagger}\left(t\right)\right)e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}
$$

Comment: Presumably the reason is because $\vec{A}$ is a *real* field, so its Fourier transform satisfies $\vec{A}_{\vec{k}}^* = \vec{A}_{-\vec{k}}$. You can therefore always choose to sum over half of all $\vec{k}$.

Comment: @Zack - I edited my question in order to address this explanation.